# Access a SQL server database from a different computer which is connected to the same router via java?

Tags: java, mysql

I know I have to do the following code. But I don't quite understand what this URL is. I mean what should I use as my IP address, where do I get the IP address for the computer where the database is currently located in?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","1234");
```

Comment: "mysql" is not microsoft sql server.

Comment: its the ip address thats hosting the sql database. type ipconfig in the terminal to see the ip address

Comment: JDBC Url is like in this form `jdbc:mysql://ipaddress/dbname` , where ipaddress = IP address of MySQL server & dbname is name of the DB you want to connect

Comment: define url as- `url= "jdbc:mysql://<ipaddress_of_system_where_mysql_running>/dbname"`
Go through the below url and create a new user on mysql and assign permission for global access from another system
 https://tech2smooth.blogspot.com/2014/09/create-mysql-user-and-grant-permission.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this format 
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?user=root&password=1234&useSSL=false");

Where 3306 is mysql port number